# Why does Trouton's rule hold true?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I cannot think of any explanation as to why [Trouton's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trouton%27s_rule) might hold true. I mean, I know it has been experimentally verified, but is there any theoretical ground that explains why it holds? Additionally, why does it only work with the molar-specific entropy but not the mass-specific one?